# How do I use ng-class without ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am relatively new to AngularJS and am loving every moment of it!  I have an unordered list of products.  When the user hovers over them, I need the list element to have an `active` class set on them.  I am currently doing it this way:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in products" ng-mouseover="showDetails(product, $event)" ng-class="{active: current == product}">{{product}}</li>
</ul>
```

And my showDetails is as follows:

```
function showDetails(product, $event) {
    $scope.current = product;
    ...some other logic...
}
```

Now, everything is working just fine, however, I was wondering if it was possible to set the class without the ng-repeat and having no `product` variable to bind to?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-mouseover="showDetails($event)" ng-class="{<i don't know what to put here> }">foo</li>
    <li ng-mouseover="showDetails($event)" ng-class="{<i don't know what to put here> }">bar</li>
    <li ng-mouseover="showDetails($event)" ng-class="{<i don't know what to put here> }">A</li>  
    <li ng-mouseover="showDetails($event)" ng-class="{<i don't know what to put here> }">B</li>
</ul>
```

How should I write my showDetails function to set the class this time?  My first try is:

```
function showDetails($event) {
    var text = $event.target.textContent;
    $scope.current = text
}
```

But what do I do in the ng-class attribute?

Comment: Why not use ng-repeat you may ask?  Well, there was a requirement to use plain HTML as much as possible so that in the event when the internet is slow (which is quite common in my area), the user will at least be able to see the content whereas the ng-repeat method will have to wait until angular gets loaded first before seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a pure CSS solution is not possible then you can create a `directive` and toggle a CSS class using JQuery within that `directive`. Apply the directive on the `ul` as an attribute or class. In that directive you can do

```
iElement.find("li").hover(...
```

Comment: First off, thanks for your speedy reply.  It's not so straightforward, I need the active class set, not for the background color or whatsoever, it's for me to load other peices of data related to the current product.

Comment: OK. On the `directive` you can set the `active` class on hover.

Comment: Would this mean I move all my logic from my showDetails function into the directive instead?  And this directive, let's say an (A)ttribute, do I apply it on each and every <li> element or should I apply it on the parent <ul> element and use event delegation to detect the current target?

Comment: Could you edit your answer for me to approve?  It may be confusing to others looking for the same answers to this question.